# Input text padding keeps changing width when submit is pressed

Tags: css, forms, input, width, padding

I have a simple login form width username and password fields and submit button. Before I click the submit button the width of the input field is `212px` as expected. When I click the submit button, the width changes to `200px`.

Here is the css on the input:

```
.textInput  {
        padding: 6px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: #15242A;
        border: none;
        color: #BFE6FE;
        margin: 2px;
        display: inline-block;
}
```

And here is the input:

```
<input type="text" class="textInput" name="username" value="<?php if (isset ($username)) echo stripcslashes($username); ?>"/>
```

It is not in any div or anything. All I want is for it to stay the same width before and after I submit the form

Here is a link to the full code http://jsfiddle.net/kEWdd/

Comment: Can You share with Your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I think you are using PHP also?

Comment: Yes I am using php but I left out that part because I thought it didn't matter

Comment: I think the problem is in php itself. I think so. (dont give the class="submit" to button instead give class="btnSubmit" or something else)

Comment: tried removing the php and changing the class name but nothing fixes the problem

Comment: So I figured out the problem. I was echoing a piece of js in the php that changed some stuff in the body of the html. The problem was that all the php was before the html tag and hence the script was being printed outside the html tag. When I moved the php inside the head tag the problem dissapeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone who answered. I figured out the problem. I was echoing some js code in the php that was outside the html tag. Once I move the echo inside the head, the problem when away.

Answer (score 1):

Hey can you please give us the full html page including the submit button and the form tag ??
The problem might be in the native style of the form tag perhaps.
Try styling that.

or try something like.

```
form{
   display : inline-block;
   width : 200px;
   margin : 0;
   padding : 0;
}
```

Comment: So i have tested the code.
And even downloaded it !
No matter how much i try i can't replicate your resulting error.
Can you please specify the web browser you are using ??

Answer (score 0):

I was trying on the link to jsfiddle and I don't got that problem. Please try to look if the problem are still there when you don't use `stripcslashes`.